# Raspberry PI - RT2870 (kernel module mt7601Usta) WiFi SUB dongle - Act as WiFi access point

Tags: linux, wifi, raspberry-pi, wireless, raspbian

I have a problem with USB WiFi dongle **RT2870** on Raspberry Pi. This is **KOM0640** (Quer) model, successfully detected by Linux Kernel **mt7601Usta.ko** module.
Specification of my Raspberry:

- Latest Linux Raspbian distro with *kernel 3.12.35+*
- WiFi dongle *148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.*

WiFi dongle is successfuly detected and can be used as client (connect with available access points).

**My problem is to switch this USB WiFi dongle to AP** (access-point) mode and enable HotSpot mode on Raspberry Pi. Here is result of iwconfig -  I've tried to set access point mode by hand from command line:

```
root@raspberrypi:~/# iwconfig wlan0 mode master
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

I have read a lot of web pages with a lots of hints, but without success.

If you have any positive results on this issue, please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had RALINK RT5370 and it worked fine as AP. I followed tutorial by adafruit https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software with exceptions that I used   _didn't_ have to recompile `hostapd`(but used the stock one which got  installed via `sudo apt-get install hostapd`) and I think (I can check if you want later) driver had to be `driver=nl80211` . But apart from that I had to do _all_ other steps, including all this 'dance with the ip tables' and so on. HTH

Comment: I looked through the tutorial again, and it looks like it is specifically execution of `hostapd` what switches the wifi-adapter into HotSpot. So technically just after running `hostapd /path/to/conf` you should see your hosspot. (Which you should be able to connect to, but unless you do all other stuff, it will not bridge you to the internet).

Comment: @DimitryK Thank you for your hints. ;) I was success with configuration of `hostapd` and DHCP server for my WiFI access point. This part is completly clear for me. The problem is appeared for driver for my **RT2870**. **mt7601Usta.ko** kernel module (driver) cannot switch USB WiFi dongle to `master mode`. For me this driver is compiled without `master mode` (AP) functionalities. How can I do? Maybe install another compatible driver for my WiFi dongle? How do you think? Where I can find list with WiFi Kernel modules paired with USB hardware?

Comment: Did you try @dafyk suggestion? Where you able to switch to AP mode?

Comment: @Shravan, no but currently I have no time for this. I'll let you know after tests. :) Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Mediatek drivers dont support nl80211 and cant be used with hostapd.
Original drivers from mediatek.com site doesnt contain AP function. You have to compile driver from [eywalink](https://github.com/eywalink/mt7601u) github repo.
After compiling/installing driver you can insert mt7601uap module and configure AP settings in /etc/Wireless/RT2870AP/RT2870AP.dat

Answer (score 0):

You need a driver that supports master mode. You can get one from https://github.com/muratdemirtas/MT7601u. Good luck